# ImportError at / cannot import name HttpResponce

Tags: python, django, web, path

Okay, so I don't know what's going on, as I'm new to Python and Django, but for some ungodly reason I have no PYTHONPATH, and even though I made one, my Python install isn't using it.

I have debug turned on, so I can give you all this: [snipped cause it was pointless, and might cause a security problem for me]

One thing that is strange is that I'm on Win7 x64 (using python 2.7) and it says I'm on NT.

I am following along with this tutorial: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03.html

I had other PATH problems with my python install too. It's like none of the paths are being set at all, and I have to do them all manually.

Should I just put my project folder into my PATH var? If I do that too much will it make my PC slower?

Comment: What @mhawke is pointing out is that there is an `HttpResponse` object which you've typoed as `HttpResponce` - the first line of the code in the django book you have, has `from django.http import HttpResponse` - you have `from django.http import HttpResponce`

Comment: Ah, yeah. but now it's giving me the same error even though I fixed the misspelling, saved the file, and restarted the server... Edit: arggg, there was another one! I need some sleep :< sorry guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in your error logs, you'll see that you are indeed getting an error in `views.py`, but it is because of this line (which is line 1):

```
from django.http import HttpResponce
```

As @mhawke points out, try changing that to `HttpResponse`.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

Comment: Thanks, will accept once I can.

Comment: No worries - may or may not do the same thing myself all the time :)

Comment: @dcsordas Then take a +1 for including the full function :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your code. I copied this from the tutorial you linked:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

whereas your stack trace shows `HttpResponce`.